# quick Jquery .load chat not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat

I have the following jquery:

```
var msg = $("#newmessage").val();
var user = $("#userchat").val();

var filename = "/inc/chat.php?msg="+msg+"&user="+user; 
alert(filename);
$("#chatData").load(filename);
```

when 'msg' does not have a space in it, the #chatData loads fine and posts the variable.

When it does have a space in it, I just get a blank div.  With no information in it whatsoever.

if I load up the php file that inserts the data into the DB, and manually type the same GET data, it works fine.

Whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
encodeURIComponent(msg)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it was something silly I didnt know about.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider:

```
$("#chatData").load('/inc/chat.php', 
    { 'msg' : $("#newmessage").val(), 'user' : $("#userchat").val() }
);
```

<s>URI encoding is done, if needed, by jQuery.</s>

You don't have to worry about URI encoding as the POST method is used since data is provided as an object [(source)](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

In this case POST may be better than GET anyways.

If you were using `$_GET` in your php file you will need to use either `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`.

Comment: This a good approach, because it takes advantage of the way `load` was designed - the `data` Object was designed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to encode your message before sending using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and decode on server-site using [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

doing this will escape/encode special characters that aren't allowed in an url or that will break your query-string otherwise (like a `&` in your message that would otherwise start a new argument).

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `escape`, `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent`, but `escape` is the only method supported by *every* browser, although most modern browsers support the latter.

**Reference**

Take a look at [this](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm) document, which does a good job of explaining all three.

Answer (score 0):

The space could be causing an issue - try javascript's [`encodeURIComponent()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp):

```
var msg = encodeURIComponent($("#newmessage").val());
var user = encodeURIComponent($("#userchat").val());
```